# Prevent ? from moving to query parameters

Tags: paw-app

I'm working on some interesting APIs that have a "?" in their path, like so:

/api/?other/stuff/here

However, if I type "?" in the request URL in Paw, it automatically moves my cursor into the query parameter fields.  Is there a way to disable this? I'm forced to use postman at the moment to work around this, which is less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, using %3F instead fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, using `%3F` should work nicely!

Another, more generic way is to use the **URL-Encode** dynamic value:

1. Right-click on the field where you want to insert the special character and pick *Encoding > URL-Encoding > Encode*

[image: Pick a URL-Encode Dynamic Value in Paw]

2. A popup opens and you can type your special character (here `?`) in the *Input* field. You should see the preview of the encoded value at the bottom of the popup.

[image: URL-Encode a special character in Paw]

3. Continue to type the end of the URL after this *dynamic value*. And you should be good to go!

[image: Add special characters in URLs in Paw]